/bin/bash: line 1: ollama: command not found
I want to pull the LLM model in Google Colab notebook. I write the following commands:

!pip install ollama
!ollama pull nomic-embed-text

I got the following output:

/bin/bash: line 1: ollama: command not found

How can I solve this in Google Colab notebook? I want to pull the model in Google Colab notebook.

pip install installs package, not stand alone CLI tool. See here: https://pypi.org/project/ollama/

I was able to install it by running Ollama's linux installation on Colab:
!curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh

!ollama serve  # start the server
!ollama run llama2  # Run LLaMA-2 from Meta

Here's the problem:
Because you're in a notebook, it never moves off the serve command, which is supposed to persist for a set amount of time. By the time it does execute and complete that line, the run command can't work because the serve command is no longer active. I'd recommend using a library like LlamaIndex instead, though they can be quite complex to figure out bc documentation is poor IMO. Here is a Colab NB written by the folks at LlamaIndex to get you started.
